# error: symbol 'grub_calloc' not found on Ubuntu boot

Tags: ubuntu

I am developing a Java application to run on Windows and Linux, instead of virtual machines, I need to use dual boot, however, after updating Ubuntu 20.04 LTS weekly, I'm trying to restart the machine and the terminal appears with an error message:

```
error: 'grub_calloc' symbol not found.
Entering recovery mode ...
grub rescue>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Since the question is closed, I cannot add my answer. But I had the same problem and nothing helped. I didn't have time to make a live cd.
But I had backuped system with Timeshift, and that was the rescue. When you setting in grub rescue console $prefix, you can set boot/grub location in timeshift folder. It stores files as is, so it can be something like (in /tmp on in rot folder directly) "/timeshift/backups/2022-02-02..../boot/grub"
And that worked! Normal module loaded, linux core loaded as people in the internet say. Grub normal console started and setting $root from there saved me!

Comment: The fact you're developing a Java application doesn't make the tag [tag:java] appropriate, nor makes it suddenly on-topic. This is a basic problem with your bootloader, which is _not_ a programming problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to reinstall grub to your boot partition, which can be done as follows:

- boot to a linux live system (e.g. [Ubuntu Desktop](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop)).
- assuming your actual boot partition is /dev/sda1 run the following:

  ```
   sudo apt-get update && apt-get install grub2
   sudo mount /dev/sda1  /mnt    
   sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/  /dev/sda
  ```
- restart your system, do not forget to remove the live image.

Comment: As soon as that answer was sent, I tried this solution but it didn't solve the problem, but today, I repeated this procedure and it worked. Thank you! (my boot partion is sda12 then I used "sudo mount /dev/sda12  /mnt") on second command

Comment: Will this help if I'm using Debian? I am getting the same error

Comment: Since Ubuntu and Debian are basically the same this should work for it as well.

Comment: Thanks, I used this procedure for kali and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no need to reinstall grub. The root cause of the problem is that the second stage of grub is not properly updated by the installation (upgrade process).

My system is KDE Neon (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS underneath), the grub package upgrade process was copying a file called grubx64.efi into /boot/efi/neon and grub was looking for /boot/efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi.

As soon as I copied /boot/efi/neon/grubx64.efi over /boot/efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi my system booted again, using the latest grub from the Ubuntu upgrades (2.02-2ubuntu8.17). For this, I had to boot with a live distro (I used latest Mint). It is faster, easier and more secure than reinstalling a previous version of grub.

Why is this happening? I do not know yet. If I have some more time for deeper investigations, I'll update this answer.

My system seems to be too complicated for Boot-repair (dual NVME disks, RAID1, fully encrypted, LVM).

I hope this helps someone.